# How to get mod_wsgi.so for Apache 2.5 and Python 3?

Tags: python, apache, web, mod-wsgi

I am trying to install `mod_wsgi`.
I use the command **`pip install mod_wsgi`** but i got an error:

```
    running build_ext
    building 'mod_wsgi.server.mod_wsgi' extension
    error: Unable to find vcvarsall.bat
```

I try to find the apropriate `**mod_wsgi.so**` file but I could not found it.

Please Help.
Regards,
Tomer

Comment: Possible duplicate of [error: Unable to find vcvarsall.bat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2817869/error-unable-to-find-vcvarsall-bat)

Answer (score 0):

For latest details on what compiler to install for which Python version, if compiling yourself, see

- https://wiki.python.org/moin/WindowsCompilers

For unofficial precompiled binaries see:

- https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#mod_wsgi

Download the `.whl` file and then run `pip install` giving path to the file as argument.

You can then possibly run:

```
mod_wsgi-express module-config
```

and it will output what you need to add to the Apache configuration to load mod_wsgi.